# WPF - Get value of listbox Data Template item

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

I have a WPF listbox whose items are defined by a Data Template that consists of a horizontally aligned grid which holds a label and button.  When the button is clicked, I would like to pass the label text as a parameter.  For the CommandParameter, is there a Binding that I can specify to get the text value of the label?

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="114*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1000"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label x:Name="JobFileNameLabel" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding JobFileName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0"/>
                    <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.PrintJobBtnClickedCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" Grid.Column="1" Content="Print" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,19,23,25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Height="70" RenderTransformOrigin="0.203,-0.173" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Use the same Binding as for the Label's Content property?

Comment: Thanks Clemens!! I didn't realize I could just reference the label binding. Much Appreciated!